# Why did Sanat Kumar gave Curse to Dawarpaala since they were just doing their job?

Tags: dharma, sanatkumara

The story that I'm talking about is of the Sanat Kumaras (Son of Brahma) visit to the Vaikuntha. And they gave curse to Jaya and Vijaya to reborn for 3 times. As result they reborn as Hiranyaksha and Hiranyakashyapa in the first birth.

Why Dwarpaala did stop Sanat kumars and what excuse/reason they gave to Sanat Kumar that this is why we are stopping you. And what was response of Sanat Kumar on that reason of Dawarpaala. Did Sanat Kumar got convinced with the reason? Did they believed that the reason of stopping them was valid?

- If Sanat Kumars believed that reason of stopping them was valid then why they gave curse to them OR..
- If they thought that the reason is not valid then did they immediately gave curse to them or they try to teach them first that you are wrong? 
  If they teach them about their deeds then what Sanat Kumar teach them?

So why they thought Dawarpaala should not stop them since Dawarpaala were just doing their job? Did they thought that we are son of Lord Brahma and great sages too, so no one can stop us? OR they thought stopping them was against dharma?

Comment: It seems you're assuming that everyone reading your question will be aware of the story you're talking about but that may not be the case. So, you may want to add some details of the story from sites like say Wikipedia.

Comment: @rickross This is famous story known to everyone when Dwarpaala of Lord Vishnu stopped Sanat Kurmars from meeting Lord Vishnu and in result they gave curse to reborn in Rakshasa yoni for 3 births. Here is wiki link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Kumaras#Visit_to_Vaikuntha

Comment: It might be a famous story but you can't assume that everyone will know it. To be honest I myself do not know the full details of it. But without knowing the details one can't attempt to answer the question. So, we need to have the story briefly at least in the post itself. Thanks for the link adding that to the post.

Comment: @rickross The story that you linked with my question seems like cooked up story. That's why I gave link in comment, not in my question. Besides, now my post looks like fool since I asking question and same time giving the answer (why they stopped kuramaras) :(

Comment: Oh Ok then you can edit that story part out.. If you feel

Comment: Although your questions are valid but what I honestly think is that the storyline is quite simple and well explained in Bhagavata Purana and there little scope of complications arising from misunderstanding . I do appreciate your enquiry , but that is making the story more complicated than it actually is. The  moral of the story is how a person engage in Bhakti should behave in his life and treat everyone equally , considering everything is Brahman. "Sarvam Khalvidam Brahma" "सर्वं खल्विदं ब्रह्म" .

Comment: @Swiftpushkar It's hard to explain my intention behind asking this Q. If I tell you in short, then I was already aware with full faith that Sanat Kumar was absolutely right that time. What they did, can't be called adharma or anything negative since Lord Vishnu also support Sanata Kumars about their decision of curse. If Vishnu himself approved then who I am or anyone other to put Q. on this karma of Sanata Kumars [cont..]

Comment: @swiftpushkar But still I intentionally put Q. coz I had faith that in scripture there must have explanation who can remove doubts of people about Sanata Kumar coz many thinks they did wrong by giving curse on this small incident. And Vishnu should have protected their doorkeepers from this. So this Q. was more like for others, not for me. I wanted that people will read such post to remove negativity about Santa Kumar and I also can be able to explain about Sanata Kumar's this deed with scripture reference to people whom I found in doubt about Kumaras.

Comment: @Rishabh It's Ok there is no problem in your enquiry , I just casually informed you. And i also tried my best to answer your questions , since there is just one ref. in Bhagavatam about the story. Keep It UP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The story of Jaya-Vijaya the doorkeepers of Vaikuntha the abode of Lord Vishnu can be found in [**Srimad Bhagavata Purana**](https://archive.org/details/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/page/n307) Skanda 3 -Chapter 15. Here  in this story we find the interesting account of  how once the mighty sanat kumaras the mind born sons of Lord Brahma once visited Vaikuntha and been stopped by doorkeepers. The doorkeepers Jaya And Vijaya got cursed by Sanat Kumaras and the reason of their welfare .

---

## If they teach them about their deeds then what Sanat Kumar teach them?

What Sanat Kumaras taught to Jaya-and Vijaya is that they are the Parshadas (attendants) of Lord Vishnu and are living in highest abode "Vaikuntha". And after great devotional service to the lord those people  who attain Vaikuntha loka do not see any difference in between  them and Lord Vishnu and they also behave or posses similar qualities like impartiality  as of lord.

Since this entire universe is contained inside belly of lord Vishnu  that is why people living in Vaikuntha do not see any difference in between them and in Shree Hari. Sanat Kumaras wondered that How come this indifference came in the minds of thesd two inspite of this?

> पश्यन्ति यत्र युवयो: सुरलिङ्गिनो: किं |
>  व्युत्पादितं ह्युदरभेदि
>   भयं यतोऽस्य  ॥ 33 ॥
>  तद्वाममुष्य परमस्य विकुण्ठभर्तु: | कर्तुं
>   प्रकृष्टमिह धीमहि **मन्दधीभ्याम्** । ॥ 34 ॥

Sanat Kumaras also said that although your outward appearance is like gods but you are really Daityas. i.e. they still possess some doubts in their minds about oneness of lord and themselves. And even though they are subordinates of lord they are really of weak mind.

---

## Why Dwarapalakas did stop Sanat Kumaras ?

According to narration Of Bhagavata Purana Sanat Kumaras were looking like 5 years children. They  were without clothes and were shining very bright from their Yoga Tapas. Seeing that Sanat Kumaras passed the gated easily they with disrespect stopped them .  The Dwarpalas did not considered their luster , they treated this tejas of sanat kumaras disrespectfully and did considered  it as very nominal , as they were not aware of powers of Sanat Kumaras

---

## why they thought Dawarpalas should not stop them since Dawarpalas were just doing their job?

They did not thought that Dwarpalas should not stop them **simply because they didn't needed permission of jaya and Vijaya**. They were having so much power that they had passed previous 6 doors uninterrupted. And were capable of bypass Dwarpalas also. But since they were in Vaikuntha they did not behaved like arrougents and let Jaya and Vijaya do their job. But since they wanted to teach Jaya and Vijaya a lesson they stopped at them.

---

## they thought stopping them was against dharma

No they did not thought that stopping them is against dharma. The Sanat Kumaras were already liberated souls so they were beyond Dharma-Adharma that time.

---

Here is another storyline from translation of [**Swami Prabhupada**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/15/) - Verse 26-37.